# Up to date message when running a make file in C

Tags: c, build, nmake

I have a make file called hello.

```
hello:
    cl hello.c
```

is the contents of it. I Don't have an existing .exe ready, and when I type nmake hello,
I get a message that 'hello' is up to date.

**Output expecting:**

[image: c nmake command prompt]

What is the reason I'm not getting the expected output?
and how do I get it working?

many thanks.

Comment: Can you add `.PHONY: hello` above `hello`.  This should make `hello` rule run all the time; probably not what you want though.

Comment: Jeez, the amount of clutter MS build tools produce when used...

Comment: @MarcoBonelli The `/nologo` switch removes the trademark message from `cl` and `link` (and presumably others)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I Don't have an existing `.exe` ready

That's ok, but your target is not called `hello.exe`, it's called `hello`.

What is most probably happening is that `nmake` is telling you that `hello` is already up to date because you have an existing `hello` file in your folder. Either rename the rule to `hello.exe`:

```
hello.exe:
    cl hello.c
```

Or leave it as is and delete the `hello` file.

Answer (score 1):

In your MAKEFILE:

```
hello:
    cl hello.c
```

The rule to build the `hello` target has no explicit dependencies and does not match any inference rules (see below). NMAKE will treat it as a *pseudotarget*. Because it is both a pseudotarget and has no dependents, it is always considered up-to-date, so the command block `cl hello.c` will not be run.

In this case, for building a .exe file from a single .c file, you do not need an explicit rule, you can use NMAKE's built-in `.c.exe` *inference* rule (an inference rule is a special rule of the form *.from.to* where *from* and *to* are filename extensions):

```
# (You do not need to add this to your MAKEFILE. It is a built-in rule of NMAKE.)
.c.exe:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $<
```

The `CC` macro is predefined as `cl` and the `CFLAGS` macro is not predefined, so is empty. `$<` is a special filename macro that expands to a dependent file with a later timestamp than the target. (`$<` is only valid when used in an inference rule.)

Try the following MAKEFILE:

```
hello.exe:
```

Here, `hello.exe` is the first target in the MAKEFILE, and so is the *default* target that will be built.

The MAKEFILE's rule for the target `hello.exe` contains no command block, but since the `hello.c` file exists, it matches NMAKE's built-in `.c.exe` inference rule (as described above). When applied to the target `hello.exe`, this inference rule makes `hello.c` an implicit dependent of the target, and the special macro `$<` will expand to this implicit dependent, i.e. `$<` will expand to `hello.c`. Since `$(CFLAGS)` is empty, the inference rule will result in the following command being run when the dependent `hello.c` is newer than the target `hello.exe`:

```
cl hello.c
```

Comment: *"The rule to build the hello target has no dependencies. NMAKE will not build anything"* - that's simply not true, it's just a no-dependency target, also called pseudotarget. It's completely valid.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Thanks for that. I've hopefully improved the first paragraph a bit to explain why nothing was built in this case.